# PDF reading error

Tags: java, itext

I am getting below exception:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFont.computeAverageWidth(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor$SetTextFont.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.invokeOperator(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.reader.PDFReader.read(PDFReader.java:258)
    at com.mycompany.reader.AbstractReader.run(AbstractReader.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone please help me on this? I am using iText-2.1.5.jar with JDK7u25 on Windows7. I wanted to attach the PDF, however I don't know how to attach a file. More than that it's a client side PDF so I am sorry I cannot share it here.

Below is my reading code:

```
public StringBuffer read() throws Exception {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    PdfTextExtractor parser = new PdfTextExtractor(pdfReader);

    int pageNumber = 0;
    for(;index<totalPages;index++) {
        try {
            pageNumber = Integer.parseInt((String)pageNumberList.get(index));
            result.append(parser.getTextFromPage(pageNumber));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error("read", "Problem reading page number: " + pageNumber + " Reason: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note: All the variables that are not declared in the method are declared as instance fields which are initialized before read() is called.

Comment: Can you post the Java Code you use to read in the file?

Comment: This is a known bug that has been fixed a long time ago. iText 2.1.5 dates from March 2009; today we're July 2013. Upgrade and your problem will disappear. Please read http://lowagie.com/itext2

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I have updated the question above by posting the reading code. Can this be fixed with the version of iText I am currently using?

Comment: If you don't have access to its source - probably not. If you do, is it worth recompiling instead of just using newest version?

Comment: Problem is if I use latest version, code complains about using PdfTextExtractor. How to read PDF using latest version then? Can you please give me a sample? Also, it is deployed at client side so I am avoiding code changes as replacing just the latest jar won't do here.

Comment: @ParagJ *code complains about using PdfTextExtractor* - how does it complain?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - Many thanks. I upgraded to latest iText version and now it works.

Comment: @mkl - My mistake. I had to change the import statements. Tx.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: The link you posted says: iText Software Group has done a significant investment in identifying and eliminating all those case as of version 5.1. which is one of the reason why it is now a paying commercial version. So is it not a freeware now?

Comment: It has never been a *freeware*. It has always been *open source*. That's a huge difference. The main change is that we switched from the LGPL to the more viral AGPL. AGPL is more viral than LGPL, which means that you may have the obligation to publish your own code as AGPL too

Answer (score 0):

The class you are using was introduced in iText Version 2.1.4 and the method where the problem occurs (computeAverageWidth()) was added in iText Version 2.1.5. The problem is that in that version also a bug has been introduced - the last line of the method is:

```
private int computeAverageWidth(){
 ...
 return total/count;
}
```

One version later in 2.1.6 that bug was fixed with the following code:

```
private int computeAverageWidth(){
 ...
 return count != 0 ? total/count : 0;
}
```

Thus if you upgrade to 2.1.6/2.1.7 or fix that class yourself you won't experience that problem anymore ...